# Formatting a form with CSS3

Tags: html, css, styling

I have the following form, and would like to have the text area, to the right of the radio buttons. I would also like to have the text area to reach the end of the screen to its right, however big the device screen is.

I hope someone here can help. 
[my jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HarrietFiddles/b8mhr44f/)

```css
.myForm {
  font-family: Tahoma;
  color:Red;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.myForm ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.left {
  display: inline;
  background-color: purple;
}
.NoteTextArea {
  float: right;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form class="myForm" id="noteForm" name="noteForm" METHOD="POST">
  <h1>Add a note</h1>
  <h2>Formatting</h2>
  
  <div class="left">
    <ul>
      <li><input class="InlineElement" type="radio" id="radioStr" name="ModeSelect" value="string" onclick="buttonGroupChange()">String</li>
      <li><input class="InlineElement" type="radio" id="radioBin" name="ModeSelect" value="binary" onclick="buttonGroupChange()">Binary</li>
      <li><input class="InlineElement" type="radio" id="radioHex" name="ModeSelect" value="hex" onclick="buttonGroupChange()">Hex</li>
      <li><input class="InlineElement" type="checkbox" id="checkboxUCS" name="UCS" value="UCS" onclick="buttonGroupChange()">UCS</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <div class="NoteTextArea">
    <textarea name="note" id="note" wrap="hard"></textarea></br>
  </div>
<input class="wr_button" type="submit" id="updateNoteButton" name="updateNoteButton"  value="Save" />
</form>
```

Comment: you can use right and bottom css to bring the textarea to the end of the screen

Comment: can you be more specific? I do not understand what you mean...

Comment: I tried your solution but unfortunately it did not work. The question has been answered though. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
<style>
.myForm {
  font-family: Tahoma;
  color:Red;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.myForm ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.left {
  display: inline;
  background-color: purple;
  width: 20%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  float: left;
}
.NoteTextArea {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  width: 79%;
}
.NoteTextArea textarea
{
  height: 103px;
  width: 100%;
}
.wr_button
{
  margin-top: 5px;
}
</style>
<form class="myForm" id="noteForm" name="noteForm" METHOD="POST">
  <h1>Add a note</h1>
  <h2>Formatting</h2>

  <div class="NoteTextArea">
    <textarea name="note" id="note" wrap="hard"></textarea></br>
  </div>
  <div class="left">
    <ul>
      <li><input class="InlineElement" type="radio" id="radioStr" name="ModeSelect" value="string" onclick="buttonGroupChange()">String</li>
      <li><input class="InlineElement" type="radio" id="radioBin" name="ModeSelect" value="binary" onclick="buttonGroupChange()">Binary</li>
      <li><input class="InlineElement" type="radio" id="radioHex" name="ModeSelect" value="hex" onclick="buttonGroupChange()">Hex</li>
      <li><input class="InlineElement" type="checkbox" id="checkboxUCS" name="UCS" value="UCS" onclick="buttonGroupChange()">UCS</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

<input class="wr_button" type="submit" id="updateNoteButton" name="updateNoteButton"  value="Save" />
</form>
```

Notice I swapped the positions of the .left and .NoteTextArea divs.  I also set their widths to percentages of the page width and then set the height appropriately for the NoteTextArea.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works like I expected it to. I am still trying to figure out when to use inline, block and inline-block, to achieve this. I think I should device some simple rules for myself to easily decide how to define each element.

Comment: When float is set to left or right, display property is unnecessary in most cases (won't do what you think it should do) as in `.left { display: inline; float: left }` and `.right { float: right; display: bock; }`. It's explained in point 3 of [Relationships between 'display', 'position', and 'float' (CSS 2.1)](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the style property `right : 0` and `bottom : 0` to bring the textarea to the end of the screen.

Here is the [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/b8mhr44f/1/)

Hope it works :)